# How to parse more information from a RSS site using feedparser?

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

I am using feedparser to fetch some information from some RSS site(like this site-- 'http://www.huxiu.com/rss/1.xml').

```
import feedparser

url = 'http://www.huxiu.com/rss/1.xml'
d = feedparser.parse(url)

entries = d.entries
print len(entries)
```

This print 8.It means I only fetch 8 news from this site.
The question is how to get more news from this site? Can I set the number that to fetch the news,like got 20 news from this site?
Thanks~~~~~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually can't get more than what's in a feed at a given time. However, if you subscribe to the feed and keep it in your system long enough, you'll be able to get more and more over time.

Comment: You means if you download the result?That is brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. The number of the fetched news is defined from the Website-provider. You have to parse the RSS daily and check for new content each time. You don't have access to older content from what provider gives access.

Comment: But why some rss readers contains a lot of news ? More than the website provide?

Answer (score -1):

We are currently building a service/API to scrape data from any web site. Subscribe for beta testing: http://textract.me/

Comment: the link is not working. any uodates on that project> sounds rather interesting.

Comment: Unfortunately, we closed the project. Lack of $.

Comment: We could scrape articles from a lot of sources, including media data, i.e. images, videos, etc. My engineer was too lazy and I personally did not have time to do it all by myself. I also did not have money to hire someone else, so just wrapped the project. It's fun, because after a while I started to receive emails from some companies, which were curious about the state of Textract.me